# javascript - merging functions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

How can i integrate these functions into 1 single function so that i need not run them in each screens or script files of my project??

I have a function call in perspective script files.But nw i hv to integrate the function body into 1 single and put it inside a COMMON scrpit file that holds good fr all screens of my project...

```
appzillon.app.currencyConversion = function() {
    var curData = appzillon.data.scrdata.Deposits;
    $.each(curData, function(i, obj) {
        var Amt = Number(obj.Amount);
        obj.Amount = (Number(Amt) * 1.490);
    });
    appzillon.data.loadData(null);
};

appzillon.app.currencyConversion = function() {
    var curData = appzillon.data.scrdata.Investments;
    $.each(curData, function(i, obj) {
        var Amt = Number(obj.Amount);
        obj.Amount = (Number(Amt) * 1.490);
    });
    appzillon.data.loadData(null);
};

appzillon.app.currencyConversion = function() {
    var curData = appzillon.data.scrdata.AccountDetails;
    $.each(curData, function(i, obj) {
        var Amt = Number(obj.Balance);
        obj.Balance = (Number(Amt) * 1.490);
    });
    appzillon.data.loadData(null);
};

appzillon.app.currencyConversion = function() {
    var curData = appzillon.data.scrdata.Accounts;
    $.each(curData, function(i, obj) {
        var Amt = Number(obj.Balance);
        obj.Balance = (Number(Amt) * 1.490);
    });
    appzillon.data.loadData(null);
};

appzillon.app.currencyConversion = function() {
    var curData = appzillon.data.scrdata.AccountDetails;
    $.each(curData, function(i, obj) {
        var Amt = Number(obj.LoanAmount);
        obj.LoanAmount = (Number(Amt) * 1.490);
    });
    appzillon.data.loadData(null);
};
```

Comment: Why do you assign all of these functions to the same property name?

Answer (score 0):

keeping the changes minimal, how about

```
appzillon.app.currencyConversion = function(curData, nameOfValue) {
    $.each(curData, function(i, obj) {
        var Amt = Number(obj[nameOfValue]);
        obj[nameOfValue] = (Number(Amt) * 1.490);
    });
    appzillon.data.loadData(null);
};
```

and then call it like

```
appzillon.app.currencyConversion(appzillon.data.scrdata.Deposits,'Amount');
appzillon.app.currencyConversion(appzillon.data.scrdata.Investments,'Amount');
appzillon.app.currencyConversion(appzillon.data.scrdata.AccountDetails,'Balance');
appzillon.app.currencyConversion(appzillon.data.scrdata.Accounts,'Balance');
appzillon.app.currencyConversion(appzillon.data.scrdata.AccountDetails,'LoanAmount');
```

Answer (score 0):

`appzillon.app.currencyConversion = function(lmoduleName,lmoduleType)
     {
      var lobj= appzillon.data.scrdata[lmoduleName];
      $.each(lobj, function(i, obj) {
         var Amt = Number(obj[lmoduleType]);
         obj[lmoduleType] = (Number(Amt) * 1.490);
          });
      appzillon.data.loadData(null);
    }`

and call using this method

```
appzillon.app.currencyConversion('Deposits','Amount');
```

Or

```
appzillon.app.currencyConversion('Investments','Amount');
```

Or

appzillon.app.currencyConversion('AccountDetails','Balance');

Or

```
appzillon.app.currencyConversion('Accounts','Balance');
```

Or

```
appzillon.app.currencyConversion('AccountDetails','LoanAmount');
```

You can call these method from your different pages for respective node name and element name.